# Is it possible to get an answer to a silent sms from a turned off phone?

Tags: sms, security, privacy

> ## [Silent SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Silent_SMS)
>
> Silent messages, also known as “silent tms”, “stealth sms” or “stealth
> ping”, are employed nowadays to locate a person and thus to create a
> complete movement profile. They do not show up on a display, nor
> trigger any acoustical signal when received.

I heard it is also possible to get an answer to such a silent SMS from a phone that is completely turned off (sure there must be some energy in the battery still)

How would that work?

Comment: If it's turned off, it's not booked into any network. So how should it be able to even receive that SMS? I doubt that's possible.

Comment: @Izzy - "Off" doesn't necessarily mean off off.

Comment: Take the battery out. Then it's off, OFF! Unless it's a super special spy agency duplicate of your phone with an extra battery - in which case you should drop it in the ocean, or strap it to the bumper of a bus, or set it on fire...or leave it at your office while you go hunt down the spies that think you are at your office. Then again - airplane mode.

Comment: @Compro01 Well, we might get really paranoid and think "they just say alarms don't work with the device off so we think silent SMS can not work then either". And the same "fake" is happening when you turn your device on and it takes a couple of seconds for it to connect to the cell tower (where it then had to be connected to already before powering up). I don't say it can't be done – but it's rather very, very unlikely.

Comment: If you search the web, there are many sites, where [they say it IS possible](http://www.pcwelt.de/ratgeber/Silent-SMS-und-IMSI-Catcher-Handys-aufspueren-und-abhoeren-6144406.html) ([translated](http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcwelt.de%2Fratgeber%2FSilent-SMS-und-IMSI-Catcher-Handys-aufspueren-und-abhoeren-6144406.html): "A Silent SMS will also be answered automatically when the phone is turned off.") . I personally doubt that too. But I could also imagine, that some phones have some decent hardware like RFID or such that could still answer while OFF.

Comment: RFID is a VERY short range technology, and just as likely (if not more likely) to be in your shoes (or many other non-electronic products - even your clothing) as in your cell phone. Either one has to pass within 40 (or less) feet of a RFID reader for RFID to locate you.

Comment: "*Take the battery out*" Alas, Ecnerwal's advice aged poorly :(. I still look for phones with replaceable batteries whenever mine is due for replacement, but as of 2018 it hasn't been worth the trade-off. Not because the trade-off between water-proofing / thicker phones and replaceable batteries is so large, but because nobody manufactures both options so there's nothing to choose from (my old Android and pre-Android phones without IP ratings never had dust or water issues, but apparently that's just me). It's also curious that nobody found the answer to this question in a decade now.